# Python datetime format like C# String.Format

Tags: c#, python, datetime, formatting

I'm trying to port an application from C# to Python. The application allows the user to choose their datetime format using [C# String.Format DateTime formatting](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/). Python's datetime formatting is not even close to the same, so I'm having to jump my code through a few hoops.

Is there any way Python can parse strings like `yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss` instead of `%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a fair distance by using simple replacement to convert the format strings.

```
_format_changes = (
    ('MMMM', '%B'),
    ('MMM',  '%b'), # note: the order in this list is critical
    ('MM',   '%m'),
    ('M',    '%m'), # note: no exact equivalent
    # etc etc
    )

def conv_format(s):
    for c, p in _format_changes:
        # s.replace(c, p) #### typo/braino
        s = s.replace(c, p)
    return s
```

I presume that your "hoops" means something similar. Note that there are complications:
(1) the C# format can have literal text enclosed in single quotes (examples in the link you quoted)
(2) it probably allows a single character to be made a literal by escaping it with (e.g.) `\`
(3) The 12- or 24-hour clock stuff may need extra work (I haven't delved into the C# spec; this comment is based another similar exercise that I've been involved in).
You can end up writing a compiler and a byte-code interpreter to get around all the gotchas (like M, F, FF, FFF, ...).

An alternative to look at is using `ctypes` or something similar to call the `C#` RTL directly.

**Update** The original code was overly simplistic and had a typo/braino. The following new code shows how to address some of the issues (like literal text, and ensuring that a literal `%` in the input doesn't make strftime unhappy). It doesn't attempt to give accurate answers where there's no direct conversion (M, F, etc). Places where an Exception could be raised are noted but the code operates on a laissez-faire basis.

```
_format_changes = (
    ('yyyy', '%Y'), ('yyy', '%Y'), ('yy', '%y'),('y', '%y'),
    ('MMMM', '%B'), ('MMM', '%b'), ('MM', '%m'),('M', '%m'),
    ('dddd', '%A'), ('ddd', '%a'), ('dd', '%d'),('d', '%d'),
    ('HH', '%H'), ('H', '%H'), ('hh', '%I'), ('h', '%I'),
    ('mm', '%M'), ('m', '%M'),
    ('ss', '%S'), ('s', '%S'),
    ('tt', '%p'), ('t', '%p'),
    ('zzz', '%z'), ('zz', '%z'), ('z', '%z'),
    )

def cnv_csharp_date_fmt(in_fmt):
    ofmt = ""
    fmt = in_fmt
    while fmt:
        if fmt[0] == "'":
            # literal text enclosed in ''
            apos = fmt.find("'", 1)
            if apos == -1:
                # Input format is broken.
                apos = len(fmt)
            ofmt += fmt[1:apos].replace("%", "%%")
            fmt = fmt[apos+1:]
        elif fmt[0] == "\\":
            # One escaped literal character.
            # Note graceful behaviour when \ is the last character.
            ofmt += fmt[1:2].replace("%", "%%")
            fmt = fmt[2:]
        else:
            # This loop could be done with a regex "(yyyy)|(yyy)|etc".
            for intok, outtok in _format_changes:
                if fmt.startswith(intok):
                    ofmt += outtok
                    fmt = fmt[len(intok):]
                    break
            else:
                # Hmmmm, what does C# do here?
                # What do *you* want to do here?
                # I'll just emit one character as literal text
                # and carry on. Alternative: raise an exception.
                ofmt += fmt[0].replace("%", "%%")
                fmt = fmt[1:]
    return ofmt
```

Tested to the following extent:

```
>>> from cnv_csharp_date_fmt import cnv_csharp_date_fmt as cv
>>> cv("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
'%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S'
>>> cv("3pcts %%% yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
'3pc%p%S %%%%%% %Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S'
>>> cv("'3pcts' %%% yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
'3pcts %%%%%% %Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S'
>>> cv(r"3pc\t\s %%% yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
'3pcts %%%%%% %Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S'
>>>
```

Comment: +1.  Derivative of J V's answer, but more clearly formatted and more clearly explained.

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski: Derivative of his initial answer, which contained only the "just run a few replaces" remark, with no code, the latter evidently being added before SO's "don't log edits" period timed out.

Comment: By hoops I meant that I have a second, hidden, text box that I use my button clicks/text box change events add the Python format. It's messy, and doing double the work it seems, but it works. Your answer, however, makes it seem like this would be possible. How does it handle the text if it's all mashed together with no spaces or delimiters? Example: `yyyyMMddHHmmss` I haven't looked much into the string replace docs, but I guess I should.

Comment: @Mike: "Second hidden text box": yikes! "all mashed together": well, you'd get the Python string all mashed together `%Y%m%d...` which would produced a mashed-together output e.g. `19991231...` just like the `C#`-produced output, wouldn't you? The `str.replace` docs don't need much looking.

Comment: @Mike: "mashed together": also read the advice from Steven Rumbalski and myself that the order that replacements are done is significant -- you don't want `yyyy` to be changed into `%y%y`, for example.

Comment: @John Alright, thanks. Mashed together is just a worst case scenario...Always have to account for the ID10T errors. And yeah, second hidden text box. ;) My dict is also rather derp-y...`{0: {"display": "yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss", "pythonic": "%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S"}}` I think this will definitely do the trick, thanks.

Comment: @Mike: Well, thanks for accepting my answer but I'm a little confused about (1) why "mashed together' is a worst-case scenario (2) TWO hidden text boxes?? (3) "derp-y" means what?

Comment: @John: (1) Usually, one would like to be able to read the date and time they've selected, and something like this: `20101106153654` is hardly readable. (2) No, just one hidden text box. (3) By derp-y I meant it's rather like a failure. It works, but why would anyone want to write something twice?

Comment: @John  Derivative was the wrong word.  What I meant to say is I appreciated the clarity of your answer.

Comment: @John: I had a slight problem with your code. I had to change `s.replace(c, p)` to `s = s.replace(c, p)` or it wouldn't do any replacing for some reason. I'm not sure why, but I also had the same problems just using a regular replace. I'm also having problems with my replace list: http://snipplr.com/view/44411/string-replace-date-formats/ I had to add the %% -> % because it was also changing things such as %m (replaced earlier) to %%M.

Answer (score 2):

Just run a few replaces first:

```
replacelist = [["yyyy","%Y"], ["MM","%m"]] # Etc etc
for replacer in replacelist:
    string.replace(replacer[0],replacer[1])
```

Comment: What would you do about ones that don't map?  For example C#'s `"M"` is the month's number without leading zeros.  Python doesn't have a time format option for that.

Comment: I would use this but with tuples

Comment: Also, make sure to replace 'yyyy' before you replace 'yyy'.

Comment: Nothing you can do about formats that are completely incompatible, I would rather put a listbox of preconfigured options there than allow raw user input, it's bound to cause trouble anyway...

Comment: @J V: (1) "nothing you can do" -- utter nonsense. (2) listboxes are a snare and a delusion; they cause endless trouble from off-by-one clicking. You must be the wally behind the websites that collect a date by having 3 listboxes (day, month, year) (so that the user can't type a garbage date, huh?) and then don't check that the combination is valid.

Comment: @John: (1) If you can find me a strftime() token allowing single digit month variables be my guest. (2) Listboxes are the only way to allow the id=10T users to fill in dates/times without having to explain the strftime format which is not exactly "User freindly", and I can imagine multiple listboxes being crap, but I've never even seen them so I wouldn't know...

Comment: (1) What you can do is implement your own formatter as mentioned in my answer (2) You don't have to explain strftime format to users, all you have to do is ask them to type a day number, a month number, and a year number -- a task that the average user can do much faster than mousing about (especially when the listbox for year of birth contains 70 to 100 entries).

Comment: Ah, but us non-americans don't even have them in the same order as you, so if it's an international application it gets many times more annoying :) IMO the international standards should be plenty of option, and there are only a dozen or so of them.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the selected answer, this is for anyone that would want the same but in c# where formats are converted from python (Convert python datetime format to C# convert-able datetime format ), below is an extension that would do the job

```
public static string PythonToCSharpDateFormat(this string dateFormat)
    {
        string[][] changes = new string[][]
        {
            new string[]{"yyyy", "%Y"},new string[] {"yyy", "%Y"}, new string[]{"yy", "%y"},
            new string[]{"y", "%y"}, new string[]{"MMMM", "%B"}, new string[]{"MMM", "%b"},
            new string[]{"MM", "%m"}, new string[]{"M", "%m"}, new string[]{"dddd", "%A"},
            new string[]{"ddd", "%a"}, new string[]{"dd", "%d"}, new string[]{"d", "%d"},
            new string[]{"HH", "%H"}, new string[]{"H", "%H"}, new string[]{"hh", "%I"},
            new string[]{"h", "%I"}, new string[]{"mm", "%M"}, new string[]{"m", "%M"},
            new string[]{"ss", "%S"}, new string[]{"s", "%S"}, new string[]{"tt", "%p"},
            new string[]{"t", "%p"}, new string[]{"zzz", "%z"}, new string[]{"zz", "%z"},
            new string[]{"z", "%z"}
        };

        foreach (var change in changes)
        {
            //REPLACE PYTHON FORMAT WITH C# FORMAT
            dateFormat = dateFormat.Replace(change[1], change[0]);
        }
        return dateFormat;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't.
strftime() calls the underlying C library's strftime() function, which in turn takes formatting directives exactly in the %X form.
You'll have to write a few lines of code to do a conversion.